# Simulating a Timeout in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, timeout

I’m writing regression tests for a part of a Rails application that looks like this:

```
Timeout.timeout(mode == :index ? 6 : 45) do
  imap = Net::IMAP.new(...)
end
```

I want to verify that in each case (*i.e.,* `mode == :index` & `mode != :index`), the correct `Timeout` length is set.

I tried using [ActiveSupport's `travel`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel):

```
allow(Net::IMAP).to receive(:new).and_wrap_original do |m, *args|
  travel 6
  m.call(*args)
end

expect { method }.to raise_error(Timeout::Error)
```

but it doesn’t trigger the Timeout. If I use `sleep` instead then it *does* work, but obviously, I’m not putting `sleep 45` in a unit test.

**How can I simulate the passage of time to trigger a Timeout in a test?**

Comment: What about `expect(Timeout).to receive(:timeout).with(6)`?

Comment: I felt this approach was too indirect; *i.e.,* that it doesn't test *what's happening* inside a given timeout. If you've got multiple timeouts in the same method then you might get a false negative (if one of the other timeouts was also six seconds long).

Comment: A false negative is unlikely. If `Timeout.timeout` is called twice or with another argument, the expectation would fail.